# How the compiler do composition in inheritance C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

**How the compiler do composition in inheritance?**
suppose that I create an object of a derived class where both the base class and the derived class contain via composition object of other classes. I want some example to explain constructors and destructors.

Comment: Seems like a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to make this overly easy for you, given it does indeed look like homework.  If you can think through and understand what's below - good luck to you....

The base class's constructor is invoked, which will - for each member variable in order of declaration in the base class - call either the constructor corresponding to arguments specified in the base class initialisation list or the default constructor if any (otherwise the member's left uninitialised, though sometimes e.g. earlier zero-initalisation of the memory the object is contained in - perhaps due to `new (p) T()` notation or being `static` - will guarantee specific values anyway).  Then, the derived constructor does the same for its own data members.  Destruction happens in reverse order.

Comment: Thank u all , this not my h.w ! if I wanna ask about it, I'll write in begin (HELP ME IN MY HOMEWORK) that's all ...

Comment: @Khan: ok... I suggest you write a couple classes with a constructor a destructor that print out messages, then try some composition and see for yourself.  You'll probably learn more that way, including what questions to ask next.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to demonstrate the basic principles, you could use some variants of:

```
struct M {  // Marker
    int id;
    M(int i) : id(i) { cout << "\tconstruction M" <<id<< endl; }
    ~M() { cout << "\tdestruction M" <<id<< endl; }
};

struct B { //Base 
    M mb;
    B() : mb(1) { cout << "construction B (body finished)" << endl; }
    ~B() { cout << "destruction B (body finished)" << endl; }
};
struct D : public B { //Derived 
    M md;
    D() : md(2) { cout << "construction D (body finished)" << endl; }
    ~D() { cout << "destruction D (body finished)" << endl; }
};
```

Of course, it's simplified,  but it shows that the base is constructed before the derived, and members are constructed before constructore body is executed.   It shows as well as that destruction is performed in reverse order of construction.

But that's only the most obvious.  You should aslo show examples demonstrating in which order members are constructed when there are severals, and what happens in multiple inheritance, as well as the case of static members.